# В блоке "Поделиться" русские соцсети отображаются неправильно

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Я подключаю блок "Поделиться" по [инструкции](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/):

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2"></div>
```

При наведении на кнопку русских соцсетей (одноклассники, вконтакте...), название отображается неправильно:

[image: Наведение на кнопку]

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Кодировку смените.

Comment: а что с кодировкой?

Answer (score 2):

Если кодировка страницы отличается от `UTF-8`, при подключении скрипта кодировку нужно указывать явно:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо Роман!!! Всё работает!