# Не сохраняется счетчик в блоке поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

В блоке поделится счетчик не сохраняется, при переходе на другую страницу все цифры исчезают и обнуляются. А также когда наводишь курсор на кнопки только на фейсбуке появляется название, а на других просто набор разных символов.

Comment: Но вы же не привели ни примеров кода, ни описания, что пытались сделать самостоятельно и что в итоге не получилось. Как мы должны догадаться, где проблема?

Answer (score 0):

> В блоке поделится счетчик не сохраняется, при переходе на другую страницу все цифры исчезают и обнуляются.

Данные счётчиков обновляются не мгновенно. Это нормальное поведение, нужно подождать.

Сколько – зависит от конкретных соцсетей, иногда срок обновления растягивается до двух дней.

> когда наводишь курсор на кнопки только на фейсбуке появляется название, а на других просто набор разных символов

Проблема с некорректным отображением символов обсуждается [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590844/%D0%92-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE).