# Обновляется счетчик

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Установил кнопки к себе на сайт, под материал.
Дело в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, к примеру "**VK**" счетчик зафиксировал нажатие, но после того как обновил страницу, счетчик обнулился, словно никто и не нажимал и не делился материалом!

Почему так происходит?

Вот сам код:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="collections, vkontakte, facebook, odnoklassniki, moimir, gplus, twitter" data-counter=""></div>
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Кода пока не видно..
Кнопка  "Поделится" - самодельная или стандартная ? )

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612754/Не-сохраняется-счетчик-в-блоке-поделиться